# Itunes Connect Archive stays in processing

Tags: app-store-connect

I uploaded an archive from XCode to iTunes Connect successfully. But the Archive stays in "Processing" Status for almost 2 days now without any change. I can't change the status, and need to update the archive for being available for testflight users.

Can anyone give me a helping hand on this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Xcode 7?

If so, try not including Bitcode in your app. Mine then processed in less than 30 minutes (previous builds with Bitcode all 24hrs +)

Comment: Yes, I removed the bitcode option. Now one of the apps has the status "created". But still remains in the processing table. What does that mean? I still can't select it as testflight option

Comment: I changed the settings on my project and its targets initially, and it wasn't working for me, so I dug a little bit deeper. If you are using CocoaPods, check that the Pods project and its targets also have Bitcode disabled. That fixed the issue for me.