# New iTunes connect, build has been processing for over a day

Tags: app-store-connect

I recently uploaded a new version of my app (1st build) to iTunesConnect nearly 24 hours ago and the build is still processing. I feel like this isn't normal? It never gave me the success checkmark on the organizer either but the build appears ghosted online.

I wil submit another one but just wondering if anyone else has had this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Submit another one. (Mine then processed in less than 30 minutes)
2. If you use Xcode 7, try not including Bitcode in your app.

See also [Itunes Connect Archive stays in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749113/itunes-connect-archive-stays-in-processing)